# How to use C# to interpret F# files in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, f#-interactive

I'm a freshman in F#. I want to use F# instead of Lua to support hot update in IOS, but I only found F# files are compiled to dll files so this can be used in unity. How can I interpret the F# files in Unity3d.

I create a F# file as follows:

```
printfn "Hello World"
```

And I want to use C# to interpret this file (not compile to a dll), what should I do?

Comment: Add this dll to your Plugins directory under Assets and then just use it as you would in C# ?

Comment: just add a f# file in Scripts and run it in C#